# Find all Files with ".py" extension with Inspect (F12)

Tags: python, file, safari-web-inspector

I need some help on how to find all files that are coded in Python with Inspect.
I tried using "Open File" and typing in ".py," but it seems that Inspect gets all of the file that contain the characters `p`, `y`, and `.`, not necessarily in the order that I specified.

Can somebody help? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Also, for clarity, the site that I am looking at is https://aidan0626.repl.co/, which was coded in Flask. I tried to look into all of the folders, too, but I am unable to find the main.py file.

Comment: I think you need to use "*.py". The * implies any file with any beginning and .py as end.

Comment: Hmmm... I wasn't able to find .py files with "\*.py", so I tried it with "\*.js" (and I know that the site definitely has JS files), but it doesn't work either. Am I missing anything?